# What happened to the Japanese Task-Force building after L's death?

Tags: death-note

I know that the Japanese Task-Force members decided to leave the building a few days after L's death. But what happened to the building afterward? I couldn't find the answer to this question anywhere on the Internet.

Comment: I highly, highly doubt there is any canon information about this.

Comment: On an unrelated note, I'd normally spoiler-tag a major character's death, but honestly, "L dies" is up there with "Snape kills Dumbledore" and "Bruce Willis is a ghost" in terms of how well-known it is, so I'm not sure there's much point.

Comment: @F1Krazy Not exactly? After all, L doesn't *exactly* die in the other Death Note movies/series.

Answer (score 1):

Ohba never has stated what happened to the Task-Force headquarters. If L left a will, his assets would have to pass to his heir (I doubt he had a legal document for that case with all that secrecy around him, but who knew). Even if L died without a will, that building still could be one of the properties that his succesor Near inherited, like the money he literaly thrown out the window. Maybe the building is now administrated by an executor (maybe Roger) or a frontman.